# Separate opening and extension penalties for indels

Tags: traminer

[ClustalG](http://www.timeuse.org/information/sequence), the social science version of [ClustalX](http://www.clustal.org/), can use different 'opening' and 'extension' penalties for indels, so that an indel operation can have more weight when it adds the first element for a new event or gets rid of the last element for an event, instead of having the same weight during the duration of an event. Does TraMineR provide the same way to set up the indel costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This feature is currently not available in TraMineR.

Comment: As a user of TraMineR, I am wondering when this feature will be available.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give you an answer. Currently, there are no plan to add this feature.